# How can I change background color of '#wp-auth-check' in wordpress login modal

Tags: css, wordpress, background, modal-dialog

How can I change the background color of '#wp-auth-check' in wordpress login modal window?
I'm able to fully customize the login page. But in modal, its background color is not changing.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: maybe the style's being overridden by that of the theme that is applied? check the css of the them, or just grep for wp-auth-check

Comment: I know what you mean.  using `add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_stylesheet' );` the login.css is only applied inside the iFrame and #wp-auth-login is outside the iframe and has padding on.  I have the same issue but don't have a solution other than to load custom admin css file which is overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create this file: `/wp-content/themes/[YOUR_THEME_NAME]/assets/css/admin-additions.css`

and add these lines:

```
#wp-auth-check {
  max-height: 525px !important;
  width: 525px !important;
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

And add this to your `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Admin styles
 */
function so31743387_admin_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adminAdditions', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin-additions.css', array() );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'so31743387_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Hard to know what you need to do without seeing/knowing the situation the code is in. However, at first glance, you could use Chrome developer tools to figure out the exact, unique selector but it's not the best practice to use such overqualified selectors.

I've done it in a pinch:

1. Right click and inspect the element you need to change
2. In the developer tools window, right click on the element you need to identify and open the copy menu. Select "Copy Selector"
3. Paste the selector into your CSS

Depending on where in your document the element is, this could result in a very long, extremely specific selector